# Custom source directory

Tags: arduino-ide

How do you specify a custom location for your sketch?

I want my code to be located in a `src` folder, but when I try to compile my `main.ino`, `arduino` complains `"The file main.ino needs to be inside a sketch folder named "main".` How do I disable this arbitrary restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I could accomplish this using the [arduino-builder](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder) tool. I created this simple bash script to do the compilation:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DIR=`pwd`
mkdir -p $CURRENT_DIR/.build
arduino-builder -compile -hardware /usr/share/arduino/hardware -tools /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools -tools /usr/share/arduino/tools-builder -libraries $CURRENT_DIR/lib -fqbn arduino:avr:uno -build-path $CURRENT_DIR/.build $CURRENT_DIR/src/main.ino
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's a feature of Processing, on which the Arduino IDE is based.

Comment: The tools `ino` and `ano` do this, still using the Arduino internals to do the compilation. I'd like to do this through the official command line interface, because those tools are no longer maintained.